# JavaScript onbeforeunload except back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I'm using the onbefore unload event to detect when a user leaves my page. The application is not a single paged application, so they could legitimately press 'back' and still be on my domain. In this scenario, I don't want to display the alert.

To get around the issue of disabling the alert for navigating on pages within my domain, I did:

```
$('a, input, button').click(function(){
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

That works well, but I can't find a solution to the back button. I've searched for solutions and found a few (like storing the users path through the application) and a piece of code found [here](https://code.google.com/p/group972301/source/browse/ep+web+for+checkout/WebContent/js/backfix.min.js?r=61) but it didn't play nicely with my current jQuery.

Does anyone have a possible solution for detecting the back button in this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: what does onbeforeload scenario has to do with back button functionality?

Comment: Have you tried adding a keyDown eventListener to the document and catch it there?

Comment: @prasun the onbeforeunload event triggers from pressing the back button

Comment: @misantronic didn't try that. Will give it a go and report back

Comment: @wish my bad I read it as before load